# Failed to call gmail api

Tags: python, http, gmail-api, urllib3

Calling gmail api does not work
Running the example quickstart.py gives an error
When the program runs to "# Call the Gmail API

```
results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
labels = results.get('labels', [])"
```

And it gives error Who has encountered the same error as me and how did you solve it?

The code is as follows：

```
def main():
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Gmail API
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    if not labels:
        print('No labels found.')
    else:
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])
```

Error message：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 190, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\google_auth_httplib2.py", line 225, in request
    **kwargs
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1712, in request
    conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey,
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1427, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1349, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1185, in connect
    raise socket_err
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1141, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=self.host)
  File "D:\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "D:\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "D:\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I've been struggling with this for days, does anyone know how to fix it. thanks

Comment: Looks like a low-level networking problem, `getaddrinfo`  is related to DNS (translation of names to IP address etc.)

Comment: Do you have a detailed solution?

Comment: The problem needs a better analysis before it can be solved. If your program cannot connect, try the connection manually from the command line. Can you connect to that server? Can you connect to any server? Can you ping the server? etc.

Comment: I changed the error message, how can I solve this